# How do I use the GroupBy function to take Year and Country to match?

Tags: python, pandas

At the moment the data looks as such:
[image]

and I'd like it to look like this: [image]

Comment: You don't want to use `groupby`, you want to use `df.sort_values(['Country','Year'])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem that what you're trying to do is related to `groupby`. Rather, it seems that you're trying to sort the data. Do:

```
df.sort_values(["Country", "Year"])
```

Comment: Thank you! This is it.

Comment: If it answers your question, it would be great if you could accept my answer.